# ManyToMany Relation in JPA with Index possible?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I want to have a many to many relation between to Entities and I'm using a junction table for it right now on the MySql end. Now I need a JPA solution like an index which allows me to use the id's of both of those tables/ entities as a Key/ Index without the Entities itself to avoid some cross package references. When querying I have the ID of EntityA and want to find the ID of EntityB with it, nothing more. This is how I thought it might work:
(It doesn't because I don't have IDs for the JunctionEntity and if I use IDs then obviously the entries have to be unique when the only unique Thing should be both entries together. A PK Class isn't working either since it would still require said references to both entities)

EntityA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityA")
})
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    private int id;

}
```

EntityB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityB")
})
public class EntityB {
    @Id
    private int id;

}
```

JunctionEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "junction", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "ix_a_b", columnList = "a_id, b_id")
})
public class JunctionEntity {
    private int a_id;
    private int b_id;
}
```

MySQL for JunctionTable:

```
CREATE TABLE junction (
  a_id   INT         NOT NULL,
  b_id   INT         NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT junction_fk_a FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES entityA (id),
  CONSTRAINT junction_fk_b FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES entityB (id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_a_b
  ON junction (a_id, b_id);
```

Comment: Why do you map the join table? What are you trying to achieve? *I have the ID of EntityA and want to find the ID of EntityB with it*: what do you mean? It's a **many*-to-**many**. So, many Bs are associated to a given A. But anyway, finding allthe B IDs associated to a given A ID can be done using a trivial JPQL query.

Comment: Was missing an "s" there sry for the confusing. I guess a JPQL Query with a "filler id" as suggested Abhilekh should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a primary key and search in junction table using a_id, b_id or both.

```
CREATE TABLE junction (
  id     INT          NOT NULL,
  a_id   INT         NOT NULL,
  b_id   INT         NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT junction_fk_a FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES entityA (id),
  CONSTRAINT junction_fk_b FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES entityB (id)
);
```

You don't need to know the id of junction table. You can query the junction like this:

```
select b_id from junction where a_id = ?;
```

Comment: Ha, I didn't think of simply adding a id which serves no other purpose then to make jpa happy but that should work, thank you!